# Is it safe to modify a .htaccess file in PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess

In my .htaccess file, I use variables (`SetEnv`) to toggle ON/OFF the website when I do updates, is it safe or is it even possible to modify that .htaccess file via a PHP script ?

To be more specific, I need to comment/un-comment those lines:

```
#RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !LOCALIPHERE
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Site/maintenance.htm
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Site/styles/style.css
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Site/includes/jquery-1.4.4.min.js
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$
#RewriteRule ^.* /Site/maintenance.htm [L]
```

Thank you

**Edit:**

My definition of safe is: I would like to know how the site will behave if the .htaccess file is opened by a PHP script and the website is being visited in the same time.

Comment: You should use an atomic write then `file_put_contents(".htaccess", $settings, LOCK_EX)` or better yet `rename()`. So Apache will only reread the file when it was written completely.

Comment: @mario +1, nice tips there and also a very nice piece of information. If the file is locked, then all connexion is pending until the file is released because .htaccess file must be proceeded before executing the php. Am I right?

Comment: Just remember that your new .htaccess has to be perfect. Any syntax errors and your entire site will be dead because Apache'll start spewing 500 internal errors due to the bad directive(s) in the broken .htaccess

Comment: The LOCK_EX would only have an effect if your Apache does also read it in LOCK_SH mode. I believe most versions do that, but haven't checked. The rename would be even more filesystem-atomic. -- But yes, the .htaccess is processed before PHP gets invoked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the file is writable by the PHP process it can be modified like every other file.

However, instead of commenting/uncommenting your code you should use a `RewriteCond` checking your env var.

Comment: Great solution. Could I get a simple example if possible?

Comment: See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond - "`%{ENV:variable}`, where variable can be any environment variable, is also available. This is looked-up via internal Apache structures and (if not found there) via getenv() from the Apache server process."

Answer (score 1):

I would gauge the "safe to modify" under the consideration if it is reliable to do so - without introducing syntax errors. To accomplish that I would recommend you use more specific comment tokens:

```
#<off>#RewriteCond %{RE...
```

That's safer to scan for and replace using simple string manipulation, thus reducing the likelihood of causing a 500 error on modifying .htaccess files. If you have different types of settings you want to enable/disable, then use multiple more specific tokens.

Regarding security itself, having them world-writable has the same implications has having world-writable php scripts or configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know, what you are doing, its safe. However, if you edit the file manually and doesnt reflect this situation in your script, it is quite easy to break it.